# How to add more condition to my conditional field

Tags: entities

im trying to add condition to my fields but it seems it can only accept 1 condition.

example : i have 1 select field for salutation(Mr., Ms., Mrs, Dr., etc) and 1 radio field for gender. if i select Mr. on the select field, the radio will automatically check Male button and other wise. if i select like Dr., Prof. or etc, the radio button will uncheck both button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to check and uncheck the field

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Checks it
```

$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it

Comment: where do i insert this query?

Comment: @chris The ease way will be to use Firebug and inspect elements to find id of both field. you can add your code in the header of .tpl file "theme" .